# Drop down shows each record several times

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

i am picking list of names from database, according to scenario each name exists many times in database, That's ok. Now i have filled a DROPDOWNLIST with those names but in drop down list each name appears several times:

[image]

but i want to display each name 1 time in DROPDOWN. I have used distict() but not working.

USING MVC 3, Linq to SQL

Controller:

```
 namespace EmployeeAttendance_app.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        EmployeeAtdDataContext DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Precise Technology Consultants";

            //var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp();
            IEnumerable<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAtdRecord_Sp(null).ToList();
            var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();
            //ViewData["EmplID"] = new SelectList(names, "EmplID", "EmplName");
            return View(EmployeeAtd);

        }
        public ActionResult ddl() 
        {
            var names = (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select n).Distinct();
            ViewData["EmplID"] = new SelectList(names, "EmplID", "EmplName");
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult showDDL(string EmplID) 
        {
            ViewBag.EmplID = EmplID;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Views:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ddl";
}

<h2>ddl</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("showDDL", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <fieldset>

                Employers 

                 @Html.DropDownList("EmplID", "Select Name")

            <p>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

            </p>

        </fieldset>


    }
```

ModeL

```
amespace EmployeeAttendance_app.Models
{
    using System.Data.Linq;
    using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System;


    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="a1")]
    public partial class EmployeeAtdDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    {

        private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnCreated();
    #endregion

        public EmployeeAtdDataContext() : 
                base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["a1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public EmployeeAtdDataContext(string connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public EmployeeAtdDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public EmployeeAtdDataContext(string connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public EmployeeAtdDataContext(System.Data.IDbConnection connection, System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource) : 
                base(connection, mappingSource)
        {
            OnCreated();
        }

        public System.Data.Linq.Table<EmployeeAtd> EmployeeAtds
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetTable<EmployeeAtd>();
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetAtdRecord_Sp")]
        public ISingleResult<GetAtdRecord_SpResult> GetAtdRecord_Sp([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="EmplID", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> emplID)
        {
            IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), emplID);
            return ((ISingleResult<GetAtdRecord_SpResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.V_EmployeeAtd")]
    public partial class EmployeeAtd
    {

        private string _EmplID;

        private string _EmplName;

        private string _RecDate;

        private string _RecTime;

        private string _DeptName;

        public EmployeeAtd()
        {
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmplID", DbType="Char(8) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string EmplID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmplID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmplID != value))
                {
                    this._EmplID = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmplName", DbType="NVarChar(40) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string EmplName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmplName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmplName != value))
                {
                    this._EmplName = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_RecDate", DbType="Char(10)")]
        public string RecDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this._RecDate;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._RecDate != value))
                {
                    this._RecDate = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_RecTime", DbType="Char(5)")]
        public string RecTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this._RecTime;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._RecTime != value))
                {
                    this._RecTime = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DeptName", DbType="NVarChar(50)")]
        public string DeptName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DeptName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._DeptName != value))
                {
                    this._DeptName = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class GetAtdRecord_SpResult
    {

        private string _EmplID;

        private string _EmplName;

        private string _InTime;

        private string _OutTime;

        private string _DateVisited;

        private string _TimeWorked;

        private string _OverTime;

        public GetAtdRecord_SpResult()
        {
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmplID", DbType="Char(8) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string EmplID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmplID;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmplID != value))
                {
                    this._EmplID = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_EmplName", DbType="NVarChar(40) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string EmplName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._EmplName;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._EmplName != value))
                {
                    this._EmplName = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_InTime", DbType="Char(5)")]
        public string InTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this._InTime;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._InTime != value))
                {
                    this._InTime = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_OutTime", DbType="Char(5)")]
        public string OutTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this._OutTime;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._OutTime != value))
                {
                    this._OutTime = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DateVisited", DbType="Char(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
        public string DateVisited
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DateVisited;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._DateVisited != value))
                {
                    this._DateVisited = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_TimeWorked", DbType="Char(5)")]
        public string TimeWorked
        {
            get
            {
                return this._TimeWorked;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._TimeWorked != value))
                {
                    this._TimeWorked = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_OverTime", DbType="VarChar(6)")]
        public string OverTime
        {
            get
            {
                return this._OverTime;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._OverTime != value))
                {
                    this._OverTime = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## pragma warning restore 1591

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are implementing distinct on n which contains all properties of class. You need to apply distinct on required columns only. Like

```
 var empList= DataContext.EmployeeAtds.Select(n => new
        {
            EmplID= n.EmplID,
            EmplName= n.EmplName
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

OR

```
 var empList= (from n in DataContext.EmployeeAtds select new{ EmplID= n.EmplID,
            EmplName= n.EmplName}).Distinct();
```

Comment: wow 2nd query worked but why and how ? i don't understand the difference

Comment: Because in above query distinct worked on only two required columns. "Select" eliminated rest of columns those were responsible for repeated entries.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your underlying object overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in order for it to work properly.

Please see here for more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx

As an example, if you have an object called `EmployeeAtd` it needs to implement the above two methods in order to know when comparative objects are equal.

This is a simple example but you may consider an `EmployeeAtd` objects the same if they have matching EmplID's, an example Equals override could be:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;

    if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;

    EmployeeAtd emp = (EmployeeAtd) obj;     

    if (!Object.Equals(EmplID, emp.EmplID)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

If your `EmplID` is an int you could simply implement the `GetHashCode` as follows:

```
public override int GetHashCode ()
{
    return EmplID.GetHashCode();
}
```

This is no way best practice but there are plenty of other questions on how to do this.

[What is the best way to implement this composite GetHashCode()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733541/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-this-composite-gethashcode)

[Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Comment: sorry, i didn't get you, please if you could say it in easy words,

Comment: Sure, give me few mins. :

Comment: thanks sir, i have spent nearly a day on fixing it, but couldn't if you can get it fix please, i have other tasks to do ahead so would save my time

Comment: Thanks sir but it's too complicated for a newbie like me, and there must some simple way to reduce duplicates, if you u can sir

Comment: Unfortunately there is not if you are using the Distinct, honestly don't be put off by it. It is a really important concept and one that can be explained easily, and implementing it can be almost copy and paste each time. I will update with a simple analogy but I'm not very good at explaining these things. 2 mins.

Comment: ok sir, imy id name is EmplID which i also a datavalue of dropdownlist items please sir, put it for me in code

Comment: Ok, try copying and pasting the two above methods into your object then run it again. :)

Comment: sir it is trowing errors:

Error:The name 'EmplID' does not exist in the current context

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46002/discussion-between-hutchonoid-and-evil-rising)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DISTINCT safely, I am not sure where exactly you are facing problem. Please follow this example. Say I Have a database table this way - 
[image]

Then I write following Stored Procedure

```
USE [Sample]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GiveNames
AS
SELECT DISTINCT(Name) FROM [dbo].[SampleTable]
GO
```

Then I create a MVC Project and add EDMX and used the content in Controller in following way -

```
public class EdmxController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Edmx/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DDLModel model = new DDLModel();
        model.Items = new List<string>();

        using (var entities = new SampleEntities1())
        {
            model.Items = entities.GiveNames().ToList();

        }
        return View(model);
    }
}

public class DDLModel
{
    public List<String> Items { get; set; }
}
```

My View -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.DDLModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("MyDDL",new SelectList(Model.Items), "--Choose any Item--") 
</div>
```

And my output doesn't conduct any duplicates -

[image]